# Какой командой можно найти документ по имени ключа поля?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Допустим есть запрос на обновление из учебника:

```
$con = new MongoClient();
$collection= $con-> test-> persons;

$oldDocs=array("name"=> "Mark", "age" => 29);
// новое значение для поля age
$newDoc = array ('$set' => array("age" =>  30));

$option = array("upsert" => true);

$collection ->  update($oldDocs, $newDoc, $option);
```

Как мне сказать моноге что бы она нашла первый документ не по ключу "name" c значением "Mark", а первый попавшийся документ у которого есть поле с ключем "name"?

Что то вроде такого запроса надо:

```
$oldDocs=array("name");
```

Comment: автор спасибо говорят отметив ответ верным, не стоит в ответ вносить правку со словом спасибо.

Comment: @Naumov я внес правку с исправлением ошибки двойных ковычек в ответе, спасибо я написал потому что изменение двух символов не считается тут правкой и не принимается как правка. По чьей то невнимательности моя правка не принята и ответ остается с ошибкой...

Comment: да я отклонил правку уж извините

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать оператор [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) в ординарных кавычках

```
$collection->findOne(array("name" => array('$exists' => true)));
```

Comment: @Naumov какая разница между `'` и `"`? Почему все эти правки?

Comment: php считает что `$exists` переменная, в ординарные ковычки интерпритатор не зайдёт.